# Swift get user input with prompt

Tags: swift, command-line

In Swift, I want to have a continous user-input loop, much like how the python interpreter works, where a prompt is made, you type a line, the result of the line is displayed, and then the user is prompted again. This is my code so far:

```
import Foundation

func input() -> String {
    var keyboard = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()
    var inputData = keyboard.availableData
    return NSString(data: inputData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
}
while true {
    println("Obl>")
    var theInput = input()
    println("\(theInput)")

}
```

However, this results in a scheme like this:

```
Obl>
hello world
hello world
Obl>
yo
yo
```

What I want it to look like is this:

```
Obl> hello world
hello world
Obl> hello
hello
```

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you still using Swift 1? `println` has been deprecated in Swift 2.

Swift 1:

```
print("Obl> ")
```

Swift 2:

```
print("Obl>", terminator: " ")
```

And instead of your `input()` function, you can just use `readLine`, which is a standard function in Swift:

```
let theInput = readLine()
```

Comment: Ok that works but now its returning the input from `readLine()` as an optional, like `Obl> f` gives `Optional("f")`. How do i take off the optional part?

Comment: Unwrap the optional with an exclamation mark: `let theInput = readLine()!`

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
For Swift 3
Note I do not claim credit for this, but it does work to prompt for and   retrieve user inputs
*/

import Foundation

print("Please enter your name:")

if let name = readLine() {
    print("Hello, \(name)!")
} else {
    print("Why are you being so coy?")
}

print("TTFN!")
```

Comment: Please include a prose description of how your code answers the question, and not just the code itself. For example, what are the relevant functions?